# Pass data to from a form to a module (VBA)

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a FORM and MODULE in VBA.   When the macro is run the form is displayed (frmQuestions), data is entered into a text box (txtName) and a pulldown (lstChoose).   When the user presses the command button (cmdEnter), how can I pass the data in txtName and lstChoose to the module?

Comment: You need to develop some code and then ask specific questions. This [post of mine](http://yoursumbuddy.com/a-flexible-vba-chooser-form/) might be of interest. The book Professional Excel Development has a great chapter on this.

Answer (score 1):

To pass data from an event on a form to a function contained in a module do something like the following:

The **On Click** event code contained within `frmQuestions` form:

```
Private Sub cmdEnter_Click()
  Dim TempReturnVal as Boolean

  TempReturnVal = funUpdateRecords(txtName.value, lstChoose.value)
End Sub
```

**Function in Module:**

```
Public Function funUpdateRecords(funName As String, funChoice As String) As Boolean
  ' Do whatever it is that you want to 
  'funName contains the value of txtName
  'funChoice contains the value of lstChoose

  'Return True if successful or False if not.
  funUpdateRecords = True   
End Function
```